# Using JS Variable Name to Name Additional Variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm using node to get a list of our Swimlanes (as an array of JSON objects) for an internal database tool.

format:

```
swimlanes = [{"swimlane" : "1"},{"swimlane" : "2"}, ...]
```

I then retrieve a list of all MSSQL Server instances (in the same format).

```
instances = [{"instance" : "host\instance", "swimlane" : "1"}, ...]
```

What I want to do, is create a JSON object named something like slInstances, that will be a collection of arrays of instances by swimlane.

```
slInstances = { "1" : ["host\instance", "host\instance"], "2" : ["host\instance", "host\instance"]
```

I tried:

```
 function getInstancesSuccess(response){

            $scope.instances = response.data;

            $scope.slInstances = {};

            $scope.swimlanes.forEach(function(){
                var sl = this.swimlane;
                $scope.slInstances[sl] = $scope.instances.filter(function(el){
                    return el.swimlane == sl;
                })
            });
        }
```

(only keeping "instances" in scope, because I'm going to be using it for something else) But this isn't working at all.  My hope was to be able to have sl = something like "1", looping through each swimlane.  And thus assign a value for slInstances["1"] = , slInstances["2"] = ....

So that in my angular template, I can do something along the lines of:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="sl in swimlanes">{{sl['swimlane']}}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="i in slInstances">{{ i[sl['swimlane']].instance}}
```

The only reason I'm not simply making an incremented array, and am using an object like this is because our swimlanes are not consistently sequential (0,1,22,23,30,31 etc) So I want it to be associative.

Am I going about this in the complete wrong way?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Created a plunker to show:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y2PjAxzsvm201EL7mQC4

Comment: Question seems more of an `array manipulation`. It would make more sense if you provide your input with sufficient data and your expected output..

Comment: possible to provide jsfiddle/plnkr quickly?

Comment: my input are those two arrays of json objects, and my expected output is a json object, with attributes (separated by swimlane) equal to arrays of objects (instances of each swimlane)

Comment: I might be able to mock something up.  I'm using a mssql query to get these arrays of objects.  Let me see what I can do.

Comment: Give it a try with debugging. Add keyword debugger at first line of getInstancesSuccess function and in browser (chrome preferred becuase it have powerful debugging support inbuilt.) and try to execute this function call. This will helps you to understand what logic you have implemented.

Comment: Why do you need the first array anyway ? to display an empty swimlane in case of no data for it ?

Comment: Precisely, I want there to always be an entry for each swimlane.  And its also because my desired UI would have a record for each swimlane (only one per) and then all corresponding instances under.  The only way I could imagine to do this was to have them as separate arrays.  I most certainly could be flawed in my thinking.

Comment: I originally accomplished this by hardcoding a separate array for each swimlane of the instances, and then in the html template, I hardcoded each swimlane and the corresponding instances.  I'm hoping to be able to make this scalable, so as we add instances/swimlanes, I wouldn't have to come back and edit code.. The query would simply return the full list each time, and the code would be able to expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want to accomplish :

```
var swimlanes = [{"swimlane" : "1"},{"swimlane" : "2"},{"swimlane" : "3"}];
var instances = [{"instance" : "host1/instance1", "swimlane" : "1"}, {"instance" : "host2/instance2", "swimlane" : "2"}];

var slInstances = {};

for (var i = 0; i < swimlanes.length; i++) {
    slInstances[swimlanes[i].swimlane] = [];
}


for (var i = 0; i < instances.length; i++) {
    slInstances[instances[i].swimlane].push(instances[i].instance);
}   

// returns {"1":["host1/instance1"],"2":["host2/instance2"],"3":[]}
```

Tell me if this is the case, could be made cleaner with underscore.js.

Comment: This looks like it is along the correct lines, however I'm not seeing this code working.  I have updated the plunker with this code http://plnkr.co/edit/Y2PjAxzsvm201EL7mQC4?p=preview  set to be held within an init() function that is run when the page is loaded.

Comment: nevermind! this seems to have worked! 


Thank you so much :D

Comment: How exactly could this be cleaner with underscore?

Comment: Actually, strangely, this worked in plunker -- However now that I have put it into my project, I'm getting an error of "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"  

The first for loop is working, I'm getting an output of:
{"0":[],"1":[],"2":[],"3":[],"4":[],"5":[],"22":[],"30":[],"31":[],"32":[]}

but it seems that the second is erroring, which is strange because the swimlane number is return in both cases from the query as [{"swimlane" : 0}] for example.

Comment: Any chance it can create the attributes of the object using a number, but then it cannot reference that attribute without using a quoted string? 0 vs "0" ?

Comment: No, F12 tools do type coercion on strings that look like integers. Let me explain the code. the first loop creates an object indexed by swimlane identifiers each containing an empty array. the second one loops through the instances and places each of them in the corresponding swimlane. I think your first array does not contain all the swimlanes expected in the second array

Comment: I thought your first arrays should contain all possible swimlanes, which is not. You can add a condition in the second loop to check if swilane exists, and add it if it doesnt

Comment: so simple... yet so destructive!  you were right, I had to fix my query.  All set now.  I really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the bug is your usage of forEach:

```
    scope.swimlanes.forEach(function(swimlane){
    var sl = swimlane;
```

Comment: I was under the impression that I wouldn't need to pass the swimlane (not 100% sure what that would be referring to in this) if I was calling this function ON that array.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: Here is the documentation on the array forEach function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

the call-back you give forEach has a single argument - the current element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

From just looking at your code I do not see why you need to combine these two arrays.

The second one instances = [{"instance" : "host\instance", "swimlane" : "1"}] contains which swimlane it is.

Angulars ng-repeat will keep each item in the array associated with itself, in this case sl. So sl.swimlane and sl.instance will always be from the same object.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="sl in instances ">{{sl.swimlane]}}
    <ul>
        <li>{{sl.instance}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My only concern with this, is I will have a one to many relationship between swimlane -> instance.  So I want there to be one record for the swimlane, and then list all instances for that SL under it.  I believe this would show a li for the swimlane and a nested li for the instance for EACH instance, rather than simply showing an li for, say , sl1 and then all instances related to that swimlane under it.

Comment: Ok, I see now what you are trying to do. Off the top of my head I think something like a nested for loop might work. The first one to loop the first array and second one that takes the value for swimlane from the first array and searches the second array and pushes any found objects  into a new array. Then back in first loop you can push that entire object into an array and the process should start over for the next value taken from the first array. Ill try to get some kinda example for you tomorrow but its late now.